# how to list all the indices' name of elasticsearch using java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch I want to get all the indices' name of the cluster. How can I do using java?
I search the internet but there's no much useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do it with the following simple Java code:

```
List<IndexMetaData> indices = client.admin().cluster()
    .prepareState().get().getState()
    .getMetaData().getIndices();
```

The list you obtain contains the details on all the indices available in your ES cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer is a big help. Thank you very much. I've used your method and it works. In the real project the code maybe different a little.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`client.admin().indices().prepareGetIndex().setFeatures().get().getIndices();`

Use `setFeatures()` without parameter to just get index name. Otherwise, other data, such as `MAPPINGS` and `SETTINGS` of index, will also be returned by default.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Val's answer. According to your method, I use it in my projects, the code is:

```
ClusterStateResponse response = transportClient.admin().cluster() .prepareState() 
    .execute().actionGet(); 
String[] indices=response.getState().getMetaData().getConcreteAllIndices();
```

This method can put all the indices name into a String array. The method works.

there's another method I think but not tried:

```
ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData> mappings = node.client().admin().cluster()
    .prepareState().execute().actionGet().getState().‌getMetaData().getIndices().
```

then, we can get the keys of mappings to get all the indices. 
Thanks again!